# Why some of my Visual Studio Code Extensions are disabled

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have probably around 25 odds extensions installed on my VSCode.

However some of my extensions are disabled - they seems to change a bit every time I start the VSCode and there is no option to enable it.

The only work around I have at the moment is to uninstall and install again to get it enabled.

[image]

I don't see any pattern. Why is this the case?

VSCode version:

```
Version: 1.47.3 (system setup)
Commit: 91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
Date: 2020-07-23T13:12:49.994Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

Comment: Have you tried updating Visual Studio Code? You are on quite an old version, the current is 1.59.1.

Comment: @TimothyG. as Lex Li answered below, this is the root cause of the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not obvious to end users like you, each extension releases has a minimal VSCode version required.

For example, the Microsoft C/C++ extension showed in your screen shot is of version 1.5.1, which depends on VSCode 1.53.0 and above,

```
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.53.0"
  },
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/1.5.1/Extension/package.json#L14

Since you are using a much older version (1.47.3), this extension can only be disabled to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is because I was in `restrict mode` [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust).

However, I didn't meant to use `restrict mode`. Sometimes, I open VSCode, and open a file in an new folder to VSCode, it does not show any message, but the extensions are disabled.

If you can also see a restrict icon on the disabled extension, click it, or reopen the whole folder by VSCode, it will let you select if trust again.